# Print the same word 3 times on the same line Python

Tags: python

I want to print out 3 of the same words on the same line after reading it from a file. So say the word is Test. I want it to print `TestTestTest`. Here is the code I came up with, but it prints each as a separate line. How do I fix this?

```
import os

file = open('rockyou.txt', 'r') 
for line in file: 
    
    output = line.title() 
    print(output+output+output)
```

Comment: If you print `repr(output * 3)` you'll see that there are `"\n"` characters in the strings. Try `output = line.strip().title()`.

Comment: `print(*[output] * 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must have newlines:

```
for line in file: 
    output = line.strip().title() 
    print(output + output + output)
```

Instead of `output + output + output`, just do multiplication:

```
for line in file: 
    output = line.strip().title() 
    print(output * 3)
```